# Express js: images with content-type "text/html" instead of "jpg"

Tags: angularjs, express, content-type, static-files

I have a simple node server set up using express 4.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');

var config = {
    port: process.env.PORT || 3001
};

app.use('/client', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/dist/client')));
app.use('/images', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/dist/images')));

app.all('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/dist/index.html')
})

app.listen(config.port);
console.log('Express app started on port ' + config.port);
```

Everything works great except that some images have the wrong content type (text vs image).

The **index.html file** is an angular application that has (as a test) this content inside:

```
        <img src="/images/family/login.jpg">
        <img src="/images/family/254.jpg">
        <img src="/images/family/jow.jpg">
```

When i look in the **network** tab (chrome developer tools) i see this:

- login.jpg has content-type 'text'
- 254.jpg has content-type 'jpg' (this image shows correct)
- jow.jpg (that is an exact copy of 254.jpg) has content-type 'text'

Why is this?

thx,

Comment: I have copied your code and tested it with three jpg files. and it works as expected. I.e. i'm unable to replicate the issue you have reported.

Comment: I'm clueless myself...

Comment: Have you tried creating a new express application with these images? I.e. new application, new folder.